# ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Getting error while running docker image. It seems to look like the problem is on my pc.

I'm using MacOS 10.13.6.
I have followed steps to create a docker image.

```
Sanjeet:server-api sanjeet$ docker build -t apicontainer .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  24.01MB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.6
 ---> da579b235e92
Step 2/2 : CMD ["/bin/bash"]
 ---> Running in f43fa95302d4
Removing intermediate container f43fa95302d4
 ---> 64d0b47af4df
Successfully built 64d0b47af4df
Successfully tagged apicontainer:latest

Sanjeet:server-api sanjeet$ docker images

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
apicontainer        latest              64d0b47af4df        3 minutes ago       4.03MB
alpine              3.6                 da579b235e92        2 weeks ago         4.03MB

Sanjeet:server-api sanjeet$ docker run -it apicontainer

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown.
Sanjeet:server-api sanjeet$ ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Inside **Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.6

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`alpine` does not include `bash` by default.
If you want to include `bash`, you should add `RUN apk add --no-cache bash` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: For me running the following command "docker run -it storageaccountwriter:1.0.0 --env-file test.env" was giving following error "ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled".  and changing it to "docker run --env-file test.env -it "storageaccountwriter:1.0.0" fixed it.  I was using python:3.8-alpine as base image.

Answer (score 2):

Issues while running/re-initialize Docker

ERRO[0000] error waiting for the container: context canceled

Steps to Stop the Running Docker Container Forcefully

```
docker ps
//copy the CONTAINER ID of the running process, ex: CONTAINER ID: 37146513b713
docker kill 37146513b713
docker rm 37146513b713
```

Answer (score 1):

`alpine` does not provide `glibc`. `alpine` is that small because it uses a stripped down version of libstdc called [musl.libc.org](https://musl.libc.org/).

So we'll check statically linked dependencies using `ldd` command.

```
$ docker run -it <image name> /bin/sh
$ cd /go/bin
$ ldd scratch
```

Check the linked static files, do they exist on that version of alpine? If the do not from, the binaries perspective, it did not find the file-- and will report `File not found`.

The following step depends on what binaries were missing, you can look it up on the internet on how to install them.

Add `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat` to your Dockerfile to add `libstdc` in some `Golang` alpine image based Dockerfiles.

In you case the solution is to either

- disable CGO : use `CGO_ENABLED=0` while building
- or add
   `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat`
  to your `Dockerfile`
- or do not use `golang:alpine`

Answer (score 1):

I get this error when the network doesn't exist.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network xxx not found.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

It's quite easy to miss the output line after a long docker command and before the red error message.